Updating tailwind config broke my layout on cpanel
I use a tailwind css to my site, first i made some changes on my localhost it works perfectly but when i tried to copy paste my tailwind config from it broke my site.
Then if i return my old css it fixed again. What are the possible reasons why its not working on the cpanel vs on localhost?
here's my code for the tailwind.config
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
    "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php",
    "./node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
  ],
  safelist: [
    'tabs', 
    'tabs-underline', 
    'tabs-underline-full-width', 
    'grid-cols-3'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          "50": "#fff7ed",
          "100": "#ffedd5",
          "200": "#e7d9d0",
          "300": "#ffd8b7",
          "400": "#fb923c",
          "500": "#a17453",
          "600": "#a17453",
          "700": "#835635",
          "800": "#9a3412",
          "900": "#835635"
        },
        gray: {
          "50": "#f9fafb",
          "100": "#f3f4f6",
          "200": "#e5e7eb",
          "300": "#d1d5db",
          "400": "#a1a4a1",
          "500": "#6b7280",
          "600": "#4b5563",
          "700": "#3e413e",
          "800": "#262926",
          "900": "#161916"
        }
      },
      fontFamily: {
        'body': [
          'Inter', 
          'ui-sans-serif', 
          'system-ui', 
          '-apple-system', 
          'system-ui', 
          'Segoe UI', 
          'Roboto', 
          'Helvetica Neue', 
          'Arial', 
          'Noto Sans', 
          'sans-serif', 
          'Apple Color Emoji', 
          'Segoe UI Emoji', 
          'Segoe UI Symbol', 
          'Noto Color Emoji'
        ],
        'sans': [
          'Inter', 
          'ui-sans-serif', 
          'system-ui', 
          '-apple-system', 
          'system-ui', 
          'Segoe UI', 
          'Roboto', 
          'Helvetica Neue', 
          'Arial', 
          'Noto Sans', 
          'sans-serif', 
          'Apple Color Emoji', 
          'Segoe UI Emoji', 
          'Segoe UI Symbol', 
          'Noto Color Emoji'
        ]
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      display: ['dark']
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('tw-elements/dist/plugin.cjs'),
    require('flowbite/plugin')({
        charts: true,
    }),
    require('flowbite-typography')
  ],
  darkMode: 'class',
}

